Which VS CODE Extension does "Auto Commit Message" comes from?
I can't figure out where this is coming from
Screenshot
As you can see in the image there is a button for "Auto Commit Message"
I'm not really sure which extension it's coming from or which feature I need to enable, I tried looking through Google Images and regular searching but I haven't found the source
I want to also have this on my other computer but I have no idea where it's coming from, and I have what I believe is the same setup and account for both devices so I really need help identifying where it's coming from

well, have you confirmed you have the same version of VSCode on both machines? I can't say I know but to me it looks like a new feature and as we all know MS is integrating AI into ... well, everything ... so I would suggest first you just update vscode on your other machine.

However, if you think its from an extension you could list your extensions here ... or try disabling obvious one (including copilot). It shouldn't be so hard to figure out if its from an extension or not ...

@topsail, yes both devices always have the most up to date VS CODE and Extensions, there is a possibility that it is Co-pilot but I can't get it activated on my other machine because my trial expired and I rather not pay for it, I can definitely list my extensions.
The thing is I actually have Sync settings on so it shouldn't matter and any device should have the same settings with the same user account, which it is

I tried looking through a lot of extensions and it doesn't seem like it has the same functionality nor the same Button, Github Co-Pilot has a different button, so i don't think it is that one, I'll keep looking

You don't have to search, just disable your extensions until the button goes away or all of them are disabled ... then you have answer as to whether or not it is extension. You could also try a "binary strategy". Disable half of them ... if the button is still there, you know it is not from that half. Now disable half of the remaining half ... if it is still there, you know it is not from any of that three quarters you disabled. Already you are down to only one quarter of your extensions. Now disable those ... if the button is still there ... well, its not an extension then.

Use the Bisect command from the Command Palette - it will help you narrow down any extension that might be responsible.

I use Codium. This extension adds a "Auto commit message" button in the Source Control panel.
